# What is wrong with this short-circuited if statement?

Tags: c#

I know this is probably really dumb, but I can't figure out why this if statement is failing:

If I enter `1` or `2` at the console, the first if statement fails, but the second one passes if I first store the result in a bool first. Why?  I am probably doing something dumb here?

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for AM or 2 for PM?"); 
string amOrPM = Console.ReadLine();

//Why does this fail if I enter 1 or 2?
if (amOrPM != "1" || amOrPM != "2") 
    Console.WriteLine("You must enter 1 for AM or 2 for PM. Try again.");

//This works!
bool valid = (amOrPM != "1" || amOrPM != "2"); 
if (!valid) 
    Console.WriteLine("You must enter 1 for AM or 2 for PM. Try again.");
```

I just noticed for the first if statement, I had to put && instead of ||, but this is confusing because I read it as:  if `amOrPm` does not equal `1` or `amOrPM` does not equal `2`, then go to the Console line.  Am I reading the definition of this wrong?

Comment: `amOrPM != "1" || amOrPM != "2"` will always be true. Don't you want `if(amOrPM != "1" && amOrPM != "2")`?

Comment: `(amOrPM != "1" || amOrPM != "2")` is the same as `!(amOrPM == "1" && amOrPM == "2")`. Learn you the DeMorgan's laws.

Comment: Thanks Scrum, I believe the word `and` is throwing me off here. When I see it, I am thinking that `amOrPM` should be equal to 1 and 2 to be true.

Comment: @Xaisoft - No, because you are using != instead of ==.  amOrPM is NOT equal to 1 and 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of it this way - if it *is* 1, then it can't possibly be 2, and vice versa. So it will definitely be *either* "not 1" *or* "not 2".

You mean:

```
if (amOrPM != "1" && amOrPM != "2")
```

(If it's "not 1" *and* it's "not 2".)

Or:

```
if (!(amOrPm == "1" || amOrPm == "2"))
```

See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more transformations.

Comment: OK this clears it up. I guess what was throwing me off was the word `and`, when I see this, I am thinking `amOrPM` can have 2 values at once for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You've got ! in front of valid in the second case- you're inverting the result. Remove that ! and they'll both behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing would be `if (amOrPM != "1" && amOrPM != "2")`. You want to write if it's neither 1 nor 2. The second works because it negating, it is either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Or is a logical or.  What it means is this:

if you enter 1 then the first condition is false, but the second condition is true, thus it fails.

If you enter 2, then the first condition is true, but the second is false, so it fails.  There is no way for the condition to ever be false for both of them.